# GSutil resume download using tracker files

Tags: python, shell, unix, gsutil

I have developing a unix shell script which will download files from GCS on to my server.I am using the command and it works pretty good.

```
python gsutil -m cp -R gs://$bucketId/*$fileListTobeDownloaded*$downloadedFileDate* $downloadFilePath
```

Total size of all Files which I am downloading is 30gb.
I am creating tracker file in specific location on the server by setting state_dir in .boto file.

I want to build retry mechanism so that if some of the downloads do not complete then instead of restarting the entire job, only those files should be download which failed or did not download in previous run.

Please advice

Comment: Do you need a solution that copies only certain files from each bucket, or is your goal to copy all of the files?

Comment: Only copy specific files for that day.To give an example there are files for each hour so we will need to copy all 24 files for earlier dates

Answer (score 1):

You can use the manifest file functionality of cp to do this:

```
python gsutil -m cp -R -L manifest.log gs://$bucketId/*$fileListTobeDownloaded*$downloadedFileDate* $downloadFilePath
```

You'll need a separate manifest file per each unique cp command you execute. Take a look at the "-L" option documentation in [gsutil help cp](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options) for details.